# Unable to use ImageRenderers for tables

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am attempting to use ImageRenderer to generate a UIImage from a SwiftUI view. Unfortunately it does not seem to pick up on the table at all.

```
struct AgingReportView: View {
    @ObservedObject var agingReportVM = AgingReportViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var facilityVM: FacilityViewModel
    @State var generatedImage: Image?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is a test")
            Table(agingReportVM.agingReports) {
                TableColumn("Patient Name", value: \.patientName.capitalized)
                
                TableColumn("0-30") { item in
                    Text(item.zeroToThirty, format: .currency(code: "USD"))
                }
                TableColumn("31-60") { item in
                    Text(item.thirtyOneToSixty, format: .currency(code: "USD"))
                }
                TableColumn("61-90") { item in
                    Text(item.sixtyOneToNinety, format: .currency(code: "USD"))
                }
                TableColumn("90+") { item in
                    Text(item.nintyOneDaysPlus, format: .currency(code: "USD"))
                }
                TableColumn("Total") { item in
                    Text(item.totalBalance, format: .currency(code: "USD"))
                }
            }
            .toolbar(content: {
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                    if agingReportVM.finishedLoading {
                        Button {
                            renderView()
                        } label: {
                            Text("Render View")
                        }
                    } else {
                        ProgressView()
                    }
                    
                }
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    if let generatedImage {
                        ShareLink(item: generatedImage, preview: SharePreview("Aging Report"))
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
    
    @MainActor
    func renderView() {
        let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: AgingReportView(facilityVM: facilityVM))
        if let image = renderer.uiImage {
            generatedImage = Image(uiImage: image)
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing that will render is "This is a test". However the table which has like 300 items on it will not render at all in the image.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a bug (maybe because Table is not pure-SwiftUI view), you can submit feedback to Apple - there is a chance for last minute fix.

Comment: I was afraid that was the case because it seems to be working with everything else. I submitted feedback to apple. Praying for a last minute fix.